# Hooking a Stacktrace in Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-2009, stack-trace

The Exception class in Delphi 2009 received a number of new features.  A number of them are related to getting a stacktrace:

- **property** StackTrace: **string** **read** GetStackTrace;
- **property** StackInfo: Pointer **read** FStackInfo;
- **class var** GetExceptionStackInfoProc: **function** (P: PExceptionRecord): Pointer;
- **class var** GetStackInfoStringProc: **function** (Info: Pointer): **string**;
- **class var** CleanUpStackInfoProc: **procedure** (Info: Pointer);

Has anyone used these to obtain a stack trace yet? Yeah, I know there are other ways to get a stack trace, but if it is supported natively in the Exception class I would rather leverage that.

**Update:** There is an interest [blog post about this](http://eurekalog.blogspot.com/2010/05/new-exception-class-in-delphi-2009-and_05.html).  Covers it in a lot of depth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To me this looks like a framework where you can plug in your own stack tracing. I guess this might be used internally in the IDE with JCLDebug. Perhaps it's intended for users to be able to supply madExcept or another implementation.

Comment: You are 100% correct. 
These new features are for third-party exception hooking framework. Now, there is a documented way of doing some work instead of using hacks and hooking.
Plus, the very valuable FStackInfo field allows to associate exception with other information, which comes from exception-tracing engine (finally!).

Answer (score 2):

No, I haven't used them yet (currently using madExcept for that, and also did some experiments with JclDebug) - but thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

TOndrej is correct.  The new features added to Exception class are for third-parties to hook their own stack tracing code into the RTL.  The default implementation of the Exception class does not produce its own stack traces.

Answer (score 2):

You would be well advised to look at MadExcept. Not only does it provide excellent handling of any unhandled exceptions (screen grab, email etc) but it has a nice set of callable routines to hand you back a stack trace that you can use almost anywhere.
Bri